# Camel route aggregation sequence issue

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm calling `transformerBean` in the last in the route but when I debug it's getting invoked in first before even aggregation component invoked.

```
from("direct:processRequest").multicast().parallelProcessing().
    to("bean:abcService?method=getProductInfo",
        "bean:xyzService?method=getProductInfo").
    aggregationStrategy(aggregationStrategy).
    to("bean:transformerBean?method=transform");
```

I think I'm missing something here.

My requirement is to call the `transformerBean` after `aggregationStrategy`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The placement of aggregation strategy is a bit deceptive. Think of it this way: specifying the aggregation strategy to use to the multicast; you are NOT specifying the place where the aggregation will take place.

The semantics is to relate the aggregationStrategy() call to the multicast. Think of it as if you were to delete the line in your code that specifies the aggregationStrategy() and move it to the multicast() call. Then, you're left with three (3) calls to beans: two inside one to() and the other inside the other to()
So, Camel calls abcService, xyzService and transformerBean as a part of the multicast. Then, it calls the aggregation strategy three times.

You can mark the end of the multicast by using a call to end(). Also, to make the semantics more explicit, you can pass the aggregation strategy as a parameter to the multicast() call.

Here is an example:

```
    from("direct:start")
    .log("after direct:start body=${body}")
    .multicast(new MyAggregationStrategy()).parallelProcessing()
      .to("direct:A")
      .to("direct:B")
    .end()
    .to("direct:C");

    from("direct:A").log("A: ${body}").transform(constant("Body changed by A "));
    from("direct:B").log("B: ${body}").transform(constant("Body changed by B "));
    from("direct:C").log("C: ${body}").transform(constant("C - Post-aggregation "));
```

Comment: Thanks man. I missed `end()`